# $a^p\equiv a\pmod p $ in field and domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

I was motivated by the inverse of the Fermat's little thm, so this make me the below questions.

First, for the $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, Is "$a^p\equiv a\pmod p \Rightarrow  [a] \in\mathbb{Z}_p$" hold? Then, Why?

(Here the $[a]$ is equivalent class for $mod p$ with the $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ )

Second, Considering a field $K$ s.t. extension field of the $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and say $a \in K$

Then Is  "$a^p\equiv a\pmod p \Rightarrow  a \in\mathbb{Z}_p$" true? and why?

(Well.. Though $K$ is a arbitrary extension, someone said it is hold. But I'm don't know exact reason why that is true)

---

I approached those as intuitively thought, So my conclusion is all the two things are true. But As you knew it doesn't not ensure perfectness.

If those are correct, Would you give me some idea to prove those?

Thanks.

Comment: Before trying to prove your assertions, I would like to comment upon the sets you are dealing with. The set $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers. On the other hand, the set $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the set of all equivalence classes of remainders after dividing by $p$. Therefore, to say that $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and also $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ is not meaningful. You may assert that if $a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}$, then $\left[ a \right] \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $\left[ a \right]$ is the equivalence class of the remainder of $a$, when divided by $p$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh, I missed that point. I edited.

Comment: If $a$ is an integer, then $[a]$ is an element of ${\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$. $a^p\equiv a\bmod p$ is irrelevant here.

Comment: And if $K$ is an extension of ${\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$, then it is not clear what you mean by a congruence modulo $p$ of two elements of $K$.

Comment: It seems to have been deleted, but wasn't this same question posted about two hours ago? Did you delete it and re ask?

Comment: Yes it is similar question with the before. I deleted and re-asked.

Comment: Plus After Sleeping on it, I had a serious mistake that try to connect the operation of the integer $Z$ and field $Z_p$ though they don't have any relevance As Mr, @GerryMyerson mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood properly what you mean in the second question, you are asking if $K$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ and $a \in K$ is such that $a$ is a root of the polynomial $x^{p}-x \text{ for } x \in K$, then $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

The field $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ has exactly p elements and from field theory one knows the polynomial $x^{p} - x$ has at most p roots in $K$. But from Fermat's Little Theorem, every element of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a root of this polynomial. Therefore, every root must be an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

As for the first question, I don't understand what you mean as $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an extension of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ since it is not even a field.

Comment: Yes. you perfectly understood what I meant.

Comment: Plus first question itself doesn't make any sense though I asked.